# How to point same domain to individual applications in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain-name-system, virtualhost

I've two applications in my webroot,

```
/var/www/mysite
/var/www/blog
```

I want to access **mysite** application as `http://mysite.com` and similarly **blog**  applications as `http://mysite.com/blog` . I'm trying this setup locally so,I've updated **hosts** file as with following line.

```
  127.0.0.1 mysite.com www.mysite.com    
  127.0.0.1 mysite.com/blog www.mysite.com/blog # May be looks somewhat foolish with this line
```

I've created a virtual host for **mysite** application with `DocumentRoot` as `/var/www/mysite` and able to access this, but I'm unable to understand whether I need to create separate virtual host for **blog** application or I need to modify existing **mysite** virtual host file ?

Following is **mysite** application virtual host file,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      ServerName www.mysite.com
      ServerAlias myssite.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
    <Directory />
       Options None
       Order deny,allow
       allow from all
    </Directory>
   <Directory /var/www/mysite>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
   </Directory>

    SetEnvIf Host (.*) custom_host=$1
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-mysite.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-mysite.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I even don't know is it possible or not,if anything is wrong please guide me.

Comment: You are overcomplicating things severely. Start by reading https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html .

Comment: @JennyD: Thanks Jenny I'll go through with link which you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need separate virt host for the blog, imho. All you need is to use alias

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias myssite.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
    Alias /blog /var/www/blog

   <Directory /var/www/mysite>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
   </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/blog>
      ...
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but its not working

Comment: What do you mean by "Is not working" ? What in /var/log/httpd/access.log and /var/log/httpd/error.log

Comment: I've given alias and a directory block for **blog** app though its not working how I desired.

Comment: And forgot to mention that I'm configuring vhost using sites-available config file by issuing `a2ensite mysite` cmd.

Comment: Could you create a simple php file with phphinfo(), call it i.php and put in /var/www/blog. Then open it in any browser http://myssite.com/blog/i.php Will it work?

Comment: its working,actually I was missing `Alias /blog /var/www/blog` previously line.Thanks for support.